# Splice index in NgRx reducer not remove one index

Tags: angular, ngrx

I try to remove one index in array with NgRx v8 and the action dispatch  but its remove all the array except the first item in the array.

I try to remove 1 item from my array and its not work.

```
Reducer:
import { Comment } from '../models/comment.model';
import * as CommentAction from '../actions/comment.actions';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

export const initialState: Comment[] = [];

const commentReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(CommentAction.addcomment, (state, { fullName, comment }) => [...state, { fullName, comment }]),
  on(CommentAction.removecomment, (state, { index }) => state.splice(index, 1))
);

export function reducer(state: Comment[], action: Action) {
  return commentReducer(state, action);
}
```

action

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Comment } from '../models/comment.model';

export const addcomment = createAction(
  '[COMMENT] Add',
  props<Comment>()
);

export const removecomment = createAction(
  '[COMMENT] Remove',
  props<{ index: number }>()
);
```

components:

```
  delComment(i) {
    this.store.dispatch(removecomment({index: i}));

  }
```

html:

```
<div class="right" *ngIf="comment$">
<h3>Comment</h3>
<!-- <ul> -->
<li (click)="delComment(i)" *ngFor="let comm of comment$ | async; let i = index">
<p> Name: {{comm.fullName}}</p>
<p> Comment: {{comm.comment}}</p>
<!-- </li>
</ul> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's because `splice` doesn't return array without the removed item, instead of this it returns the array consists of removed items :)

to make it work you should do sth like this:

```
on(CommentAction.removecomment, (state, { index }) => {
   const array = [...state];
   array.splice(index, 1);
   return array;
})
```